# 2 Forms in a page, Get the Value from the other form

Tags: php, html

I have 2 HTML form in a page

```
<form action="my-page.php" method="post" id="savedata" name="savedata">
    <input class="text" name="myname" value="" type="text" />
    <input class="text" name="myaddress" value="" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

<form action="my-page.php" method="post" id="previewdata" name="previewdata">
    <input type="submit" value="Preview" />
</form>
```

The first one [savedata] will save the data to MySQL after clicking the [Save Button]

The second one [previewdata] will preview (means will just show in the page using HTML) the data once the [Preview Button] was clicked

How can the 2nd form get the data from the 1st form?

Comment: You can get the data from any form using Javascript. But do you mean get it on the server? Why not combine them into a single form, since they both go to the same server script?

Comment: Addition,combine in one form, and then use html5 formaction for two submit button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to using 2 different forms you could have a single form with 2 submit buttons:

```
<form action="my-page.php" method="post">
    <input class="text" name="myname" value="" type="text" />
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="save">Save</button>
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="preview">Preview</button>
</form>
```

Now inside your server side script look for `$_POST["action"]` and act accordingly.

Also in HTML5 there's the [`formaction`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.submit.html#button.submit.attrs.formaction) attribute that could be specified on a submit button to invoke a different server side script.

Comment: How would I know which button was clicked?

Comment: I've already covered that part in my answer. I quote: `Now inside your server side script look for $_POST["action"] and act accordingly.` If the value is `save` then the Save button was clicked and if the value is `preview` then the Preview button was clicked.

Comment: Sorry I dont know about that because in the past I only captured which button was click by putting a variable in the form.

Comment: How does putting a variable in the form helps you know which button was clicked? Maybe you used javascript or something? That's unnecessary. HTML provides you all the tools you need for this.

Comment: I put a variable in the form like this <input type="hidden" name="action" value="preview" />. Then in php Ill check if ($action == "preview"). $action is always black if the form is not yet submitted hence I know if $action = "something" the form is already submitted

Comment: But this means that you had 2 forms. I am suggesting you using a single form for this task.

Comment: Yeah This is the first time Ill be using 2 buttons in a form. Thanks